# Asp.net Core Persistent Authentication - Custom Cookie Authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get a persistent connection so the users only have to use their password once. I've used this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x but the users still get disconnected after a while.

```
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    principal,
                    new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent = true
                    });
```

What can I do to get a really persistent connection ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The persistence granted by IsPersistent is, according to the docs, only meant to imply that the authentication will persist through browsing sessions (that is, it is kept even when the browser is closed). You need a combination of Persistence *and* to set an expiration time for the cookie. The expiration of the cookie can be set via the [CookieAuthenticationOptions (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.cookieauthenticationoptions), using the *ExpireTimeSpan* option.

Without persistence, expiration of the authentication can be set using the *ExpiresUtc* option in AuthenticationOptions,

Comment: Alright I'll try that. Just one thing, the doc says: The ExpiresUtc and IsPersistent properties are mutually exclusive. Doesn't that mean I can't use both at the same time ?

Comment: @GlobalFx So absolute expiry (via ExpiresUtc) will reject the set cookie even if the user hasn't closed the browser. _IsPersistent_ means that the user's authentication lifetime is then dictated by the CookieAuthenticationOptions.  
Setting isPersistent to false means that users are only authenticated for their current browsing session, which will be cleared when the browser is closed.

Comment: Ok, so the solution would be to set _IsPersistent_ to true and set _ExpireTimeSpan_ to let's say a year in _ConfigureServices_ without setting _ExpiresUtc_. The users would only have to login once a year right ?

Comment: I believe so! No matter what your app uses cookies. If you don't have persistence set, then the cookies are cleared on closing the browser. If you _do_ have persistence, then the cookies need an expiration date, set by your TimeSpan.

Comment: Great ! Wanna update your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 4):

There are few things you should notice when implement persistent cookie authentication.

Configure sliding expiration for cookie in Startup.cs. It will be clearer if you explicitly set values that you needed and don't use default settings.

```
private void ConfigureAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {                 
            // true by default   
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;

            // 14 days by default
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        });
}
```

When user check flag "Remember Me" configure cookie to persist across browser sessions and set absolute expiration (as long as you want). This settings will override SlidingExpiration and ExpireTimeSpan. In login action:

```
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
// Prepare user claims...
                
var userIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(userIdentity);

AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = model.RememberMe };
if (model.RememberMe)
{
    // One month for example
    authenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);
}

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal, authenticationProperties);
```

Confugure data protection. Remember machineKey in old classic asp.net webforms. Otherwise cookie will be reset after every IIS app pool restart. You should configure data protection before authentication in Startup.cs. To store keys in root folder of your app:

```
private void ConfigureDataProtection(IServiceCollection services, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
{
    var keysDirectoryName = "Keys";
    var keysDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(environment.ContentRootPath, keysDirectoryName);
    if (!Directory.Exists(keysDirectoryPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(keysDirectoryPath);
    }
    services.AddDataProtection()
          .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(keysDirectoryPath))
          .SetApplicationName("YourApplicationName");
}
```

From docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: this should mark as Accepted Answer

Comment: is there a connection between the call to `.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` and `.AddCookie` ?